# Lubuntu 20.04 cannot execute .sh script from PCManFM-Qt

Tags: lubuntu, sh, pcmanfm

Lubuntu 20.04. I've created a simple .sh script to run my Java program, so content of .sh is:

`java -jar /path_to_my/test.jar`

I marked this script as executable, and when double-clicking on it in the file manager (PCManFM-Qt v. 0.14.1) it just opens a terminal (QTerminal) and does nothing.

When executing the script manually in the terminal it works.

Comment: Did you script have a *shebang*?  I'm not on *focal* currently, but a simple script containing shebang ("#!/bin/bash"), `echo blah` and `sleep 4` executed correctly (on my later release Lubuntu using LXQt) when double-clicked in `pcmanfm-qt`

Comment: Thank you, adding ```#!/bin/bash``` to the beginning of the script helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system has to know what type of script it is.  That is done via the use of a "*shebang*"

For a simple bash script you can use

```
#!/bin/bash
echo blah
sleep 4
```

It worked for you in `bash` (terminal) as your `bash` terminal made an assumption you were trying to run a `bash` script. `pcmanfm-qt` cannot really make that assumption, so the *shebang* tells the system what type of script it is.

(*You already had the executable flag correct that was also required*)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the script has helped